# I got error of using "print-xml" in Lisp when I follow the example of s-xml homepage

Tags: xml, lisp, common-lisp

s-xml home: http://common-lisp.net/project/s-xml/

I use Clozure CL to run Lisp. It works fine so far.

Then I tried s-xml like below:

```
Welcome to Clozure Common Lisp Version 1.7-dev-r14406M-trunk  (DarwinX8664)!
? (load "~/quicklisp/setup.lisp")
#P"/Users/zijia/quicklisp/setup.lisp"
? (ql:quickload "s-xml")
To load "s-xml":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    s-xml
; Loading "s-xml"

("s-xml")
? (in-package :s-xml)
#<Package "S-XML">
? (print-xml '(p "Interesting stuff at " ((a href "http://slashdot.org") "SlashDot")))
<
> Error: There is no applicable method for the generic function:
>          #<STANDARD-GENERIC-FUNCTION GET-PREFIX #x302000AB172F>
>        when called with arguments:
>          (NIL)
> While executing: #<CCL::STANDARD-KERNEL-METHOD NO-APPLICABLE-METHOD (T)>, in process listener(1).
> Type :GO to continue, :POP to abort, :R for a list of available restarts.
> If continued: Try calling it again
> Type :? for other options.
1 >
```

(print-xml '(p "Interesting stuff at " ((a href "http://slashdot.org") "SlashDot"))) is copied from http://common-lisp.net/project/s-xml/. The rest examples are running fine. What's wrong with this "print-xml"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I get the same in SBCL.  A quick inspection in Slime finds the following variable:

```
(defvar *ignore-namespaces* nil
  "When t, namespaces are ignored like in the old version of S-XML")
```

I think that the documentation at common-lisp.net is outdated.  A quick fix for you would be to `let` or `setf` this variable to `t`, which would cause `print-identifier` to just print that identifier.

I do not know how the namespaces are meant to be used; you could try to find that in more current documentation, diving into the code, or contacting the author.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Where can I find the latest s-xml document? the common-lisp.net one is the latest one I can find.

Answer (score 0):

First, 'print-xml' is outdated of course. You can write your own print xml function. And you do not even need documentation, because the interface of s-xml is very simple. So check out xml.lisp to browse the source code. :)